# VBoxManage throwing VERR_ACCESS_DENIED error on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, file-permissions, openwrt, administrator

I'm attempting to [follow these instructions](https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/howto/virtualbox) to set up OpenWrt on Virtual Box on Windows 10. I installed Virtual Box 6.1.4 on Windows 10. I configured my environment variables to have access to the VBox executables so I could run `VBoxManage convertfromraw openwrt-15.05.1-x86-64-combined-ext4.img openwrt.vdi --format VDI`. However, when I run that command (from Powershell or cmd, both of which I ran as an administrator), I get the following error:

```
Converting from raw image file="openwrt-15.05.1-x86-64-combined-ext4.img" to file="openwrt.vdi"...
VBoxManage.exe: error: Cannot open file "openwrt-15.05.1-x86-64-combined-ext4.img": VERR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

What can I do to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

- use 7zip to extract `.gz` file/
- create a folder in Documents eg test
- run cmd ad admin (right click run as administrator)
- cd ....Documents\test (... your  computer eg c:\users\john)
- type command `"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" convertfromraw --format VDI openwrt-bcm27xx-bcm2711-rpi-4-ext4-factory.img openwrt.vdii`
  (with  "" included exactly as I wrote)

and it's done.

I had the same problem  and I found the solution on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwPD1GWw5go).

Seems a discompability in extraction.